# Handling large Excel files with shared strings

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Using OpenXML, Microsoft recommends using the SAX approach:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx

So rather than loading the whole document DOM in memory, you can read the file serially with `OpenXmlReader`. For example:

```
WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();

OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);
string text;
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue))
    {
        text = reader.GetText();
        Console.Write(text + " ");
    }
}
```

But this kinda falls down when you have cells with the `SharedString` data type. Those are stored separate from the sheet data in the shared string table and, as far as I can see, there's no real way to avoid having to load the entire shared string table. For example, I can do this:

```
var sharedStrings = wbPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Cast<SharedStringItem>()
                       .Select(i => i.Text.Text).ToArray();
```

And then I can do something like:

```
var row = reader.LoadCurrentElement() as Row; 
var cells = row.Descendants<Cell>();
var cellValues = cells.Select(c => c.DataType != null 
     && c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString ? 
     sharedStrings[int.Parse(c.CellValue.Text)] : c.CellValue.Text).ToArray();
```

Which works, but I had to load the entire shared string table, which could be very large if the file has a lot of unique strings. Is there a more efficient way handle looking up the shared strings as your process each row of the file?